# How to auto-Merge Bitbucket branches from Bamboo?

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo, automerge

We are working on a POC with Bamboo and Bitbucket to do an auto-merge between the Master and Feature branches.

The task list is as follows:

- Commit code in trunk
- Get a repository polled bamboo build for the Trunk
- Code gets Auto-merge in feature branch
- Get a repository polled bamboo build for the Feature

I am able to do the first two steps but the next two are coming through.
What can be the configuration issue in this plan?

Thanks

Comment: Your description looks similar to feature request in Bamboo issue tracker - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-12646

Comment: Hi Oleksiy
I looked it up in the Issue tracker, I am not sure if the feature is added yet.

Comment: It's not implemented yet

Comment: Got it sorted by linking the repository in Bamboo

Answer (score 2):

You can establish automerging from your Bamboo plan.

Go to Plan **Configuration -> Merging -> Branch merging enabled** and you have 2 options:

- Branch updater
- Gatekeeper

For your user case you can use **Branch updater**, selecting the merged from the branch that you want and pushing on the branch that you want.